# SYSINFO.NWinMajor is giving wrong value for Windows 7

Tags: installscript, installshield-2012

I am creating installer using InstallShield 2012 and I am checking OS using SYSINFO major and minor values.SYSINFO.nWinMajor is giving correct value but SYSINFO.nWinMinor is giving 0 for windows 7.It should be 1.

Do anyone know the solution for above ?

Comment: Is this in a pure InstallScript project, or in an InstallScript custom action inside an MSI project? (If the latter, try referencing the MSI property `VersionNT`.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I know about VersionNT.But I am using nWinMajor and in combination I want to use nWinMinor. so want to know the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom actions within an MSI are shimmed with `VistaRTMVersionLie` on Windows 7 so that the APIs which InstallShield uses to populate `SYSINFO` are claiming to run on Windows Vista. This cannot be disabled by the installation itself, so your best bet is to reference the `VersionNT` or `VersionNT64` properties (possibly indirectly in the case of a deferred action), as they have the correct version information.

See Chris Jackson's [Why Custom Actions get a Windows Vista Version Lie on Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/05/06/why-custom-actions-get-a-windows-vista-version-lie-on-windows-7.aspx) for additional details, such as information on why shim is applied.

Comment: Thanks all for your response